# Windows Shell Extension Not Calling Initialize

Tags: c++, windows, shell, com, contextmenu

I was hoping somebody here had some insight into what could be causing this problem. I've implemented several COM extensions for Explorer that provide ShellIconOverlays and a ContextMenu, and the overlays work perfectly. The Context Menu works fine when I click on the desktop but when I right click in any explorer instance, I can see the interface being queried in the debugger and an instance of IShellExtInit being generated but the initialize function doesn't get called in the explorer instances, but it is called fine from the desktop and a ContextMenu item is queried immediately after.

Has anybody here seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 2):

If you're debugging a shell extension, chances are that you've had occasions to terminate the running explorer.exe process and start a new one.  When you started a new one, was it running with the same integrity level as the original?

Do your Explorer settings say to browse files in a new process?  If so, is that process running with the same integrity level as the original?

Also, since you're running a debugger, chances are that you built a debug build.  Does explorer.exe sometimes try to load the debug build of your DLL and sometimes try to load the release build of your DLL?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "Integrity Level" portion of your answer? I'm running into this exact same problem, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEq1S2y6Y14 , release build etc. I do get the createAggregate() and queryInterface() calls to the instance of IShellExtInit, but Initialize is never called. It *is* called when this is run from the desktop, open-window dialogs etc.

Comment: There are many MSDN articles and blog postings by numerous authors.  Integrity levels are high, medium, and low.  Applications running at different integrity levels are insulated from each other, even in the same desktop.  Usually the explorer.exe process is running at medium integrity.  If someone runs Visual Studio as administrator and debugs a process then it might be high integrity.  In some cases explorer.exe might be running at high integrity so the problem might be the opposite, if an application is running at medium integrity.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be unrelated - I always assumed that the integrity concept was introduced around Vista, and I've been experiencing these bugs in XP.

Comment: You are right that integrity levels were introduced with Vista.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I run into the exact same problem here, and it turns out that the issue has to do with

```
ThreadingModel = Apartment
```

Basically, what I think you are experiencing, is that the **second** thread of explorer.exe (desktop runs in STA thread) uses the default (legacy) `ThreadingModel` - and expects your `COM` to implement `IMarshal` to do IPC. `Apartment` `ThreadingModel` allows multiple instances of your `IShellExt` class to co-exist.

---

*Caveat* - If you are using `ActiveQt` to develop Context Menu Shell Extensions, there are few more tricks to use.